# Is it true that $\operatorname{Im} f$ is closed in $\Bbb R$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ be a continuous function  such that $f(i)=0\ \forall i\in \Bbb Z$ .Then is it true  that $\operatorname{Im} f$ is closed in $\Bbb R$?

Let $x_n$ be a sequence in  $\operatorname{Im} f$ such that $x_n\to x$

We should show that $x\in  \operatorname{Im} f$.

How should I proceed now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is quite false; what *is* true is that the image of each interval $[i, i + 1]$ is closed (e.g. as an application of the intermediate value theorem). The countable union of closed sets need not be closed, however, and this should be a hint about how to construct a counterexample.

Comment: can $f$ be uniformly continuous ?

Comment: @Amartya Sure it can. Just make sure that the continuity doesn't get too much worse with each passing interval.

Comment: Can it be proved using the above hypothesis that $f$ is always uniformly continuous

Comment: No, it cannot be proven to always be uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is no. Let $f(x)=\sin (2\pi x)\cdot\arctan x$. Its image is $\left(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right)$

Notice that $f$ is Lipschitz continuous, since $|f'(x)|\le\pi^2+1$.

Answer (score 2):

It's not true.  Suppose, for example that $f(x)=0$ for $x\le 0$ and on each interval from $n$ to $n+1$ for $n\in\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$, as $x$ goes from $n$ to $n+1$, $f(x)$ goes from $0$ up to $a_n$ and then back down to $0$, and $a_n$ increases and approaches $1$ from below as $n\to\infty$.  Then the image of $f$ is $[0,1)$, and that is not closed.

Comment: from the above can $f$ be uniformly continous

Comment: @Amartya : Did you try constructing an example using the hint? Try to do that first, then check if the function you get is uniform continuous.

Comment: I am not getting the example @JohnMa

Comment: How is this function written @JohnMa

Comment: For example can you write down a function on $[0,1]$ so that $f(0) = f(1) = 0$ and (for example) $f(1/2) = 4$? @Amartya

Comment: $f(x)=-16x(x-1)$

Comment: Yes, try to do that for each interval. On $[n, n+1]$ you want a function which is $f(n) = f(n+1) = 0$ and $f(n + 1/2) = 1-1/n$. @Amartya